# W10 RDP connecting slow if using computer name

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, remote-connection

I have two Windows 10 Professional computers:

- Surface 3: W10 Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.447)
- PC: W10 21H2 (OS Build 19044.1889).

Issue: I'm trying to remotely connect from PC to Surface 3 using Windows RDP, and if I'm using the Surface 3's computer name to do this the connection initialization will take around 60 seconds:

[image]

Using the IP address of Surface 3 - instead of computer name - solves this issue and the connection is initiated in less than 5 seconds.

How can I fix this slow connection initialization when using computer name?

Comment: Are you connected to an AD domain that is acting as your DNS server?

Comment: @Ramhound  I would think so, Surface 3 is exposing a WiFi network (mobile hotspot) to which the PC connects.

Comment: In order to answer your question, the answer to that question, needs to be an absolute "Yes" or "No".  "I would think so" isn't an affirmative and the correct answer demands on the answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I fix this slow connection initialization when using computer
> name?

Use an entry in your HOSTS file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc):

Example:   #  102.54.94.97 rhino.acme.com   # source server

```
(1) Edit the HOSTS file with Notepad run as Administrator.
(2) Set up the HOSTS file on the target system (the one you are trying to access).
```

You can set up your HOSTS file on both systems to be sure